# Adding a Skip Button to FastForward a .fadeIn / .fadeOut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

Just to clarify, when you load my site I have a bit of text that fades in (quote), and then fades out. Afterwards a new bit of text (my brand name) fades in.

Since I want people to have enough time to read the first text (the quote) the fade in and fade out are a bit long, however I don't want people to get impatient after visiting the site for the 5th time and having to wait every time.

Therefore I was thinking of a "skip-like" button or text (IE: SKIP) so that they can fastforward to where the brand name fades in.

Any help would be appreciated!!! Here's an example of what I currently have!!

http://jsfiddle.net/K6SpB/

### HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<center>
   <div id="mytext" align="center">
      <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
         <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                     <td height="200">
                        <center>
                           <font size="4px" id="quote" color="black">THIS IS A QUOTE.</font>
                           <br>
                           <font size="12px" id="brandname" color="black">BRAND NAME.</font>
                        </center>
                     </td>                
                  </tr>    
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</center>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quote').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(5000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
    $('#brandname').hide().delay(11500).fadeIn(2000);
});​
```

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
   #quote, #brandname {
      position:relative;
      display: none;
      float:center;
   }
   #mytext {

   }
</style>​
```

Comment: If you're considering adding a skip for something you deemed mandatory, you're doing something wrong. Skip buttons should only really be used for game cutscenes and other sequences, not for what you're describing.

Comment: "I'm worried that this will be annoying" is the first sign that you're making a poor design choice.

Comment: Not necessarily. I love sites that have a small intro (especially fashion) however after the 5th time of checking out the site, I get bored of seeing the same intro (I just want to get to the collections). They have a skip option which is cool. I want something similar. Maybe skipping the quote script and moving onto the brand name fade in? I'm sure it could be possible.

Comment: I have 30 different statements that I randomly select from to display on each refresh, so the user doesn't always see the same one. ;) Keeps it fresh. I just want to provide an option for those that dont care for statements, that's all. I don't see a downside to it. But thanks for the feedback, I thought the same thing before. Maybe it's just me getting annoyed each refresh bc as I keep coding and checking it constantly, I have to keep waiting to get to the part I coded.

Comment: `<center>`? really? The `<center>` element is deprecated in HTML 4.01... usee CSS instead!

Comment: I wrote this quickly. I check my code with http://validator.w3.org/ afterwards, sigh can anyone just try to answer the question? Is it possible? If so any suggestions on how to do it? I'm not asking if it's the best way to approach design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want jQuery .stop() (http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

So, if you add a Skip link:

```
<a href="#" id="skip">Skip</a>
```

The code would look like this:

```
$('#skip').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#quote, #brandname').stop(true, true);
});
```

The first "true" tells jQuery to remove any pending animations from the animation queue, the second "true" tells it to skip straight to the end of the animation.

Comment: And since you don't really know the state of the animation, follow it up by the desired end state: `.stop(true, true).hide()`

Comment: You guys are awesome! Yeah instead of the .hide() I placed a .fadeOut(500) to make it a bit cleaner. How would I start the animation for brandname immediately. As of now it still waits until the set time for it to appear. :/

Comment: I think I figured it out! I did the following:  `$('#skip').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#quote').stop(true, false).fadeOut(500);
    $('#brandname').stop(true,false).delay(500).fadeIn(2000);
});`