# Javascript - fadein and fadeout multiple divs at the same time after x time and add a skip button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, fade

I don't know much of javascript/jquery and I really need some help. 
I'm doing a website that plays a fullscreen html5 video on load and after an x amount of time it fades in other content. I have set delay fadeIn functions for that other content and delay fadeOut for the video div. This video div is replaced by another video that loops (I couldn't figure out a way to change the src, so this div fades in when the other fades out). The content that fades in has position:fixed and display:none. The code I have right now works, but I can't manage to ad a skip button that skips the delay time and plays the fades immediately. I have tried other solutions I found here on stackoverflow but none of the worked in full (probably because how my code is written). 
My goal is to skip the video and fade in the other content if the button is clicked and if not the content loads after delay runs out. Also, maybe change the src of the video instead of switching divs (but this is not that important).

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="v1">
        <video autoplay poster="screenshot.jpg" id="background" controls>
            <source src="http://www.ray-gun.pt/clientes/Natal_2016/RayGun_NatalparaTodoAno_sem_nada.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="100%" height="auto">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div id="vloop">
        <video autoplay loop poster="screenshot.jpg" id="background" controls>
            <source src="http://www.ray-gun.pt/clientes/Natal_2016/NATAL_SO_PRODUTO.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="100%" height="auto">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="skipbtn">
        <img src="images/skip.png" alt="saltar" />
    </a>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="show1" class="content faded">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="social">
                    <div>
                        <a class=fb href="https://www.facebook.com/RayGun.LX/?fref=ts" target="_blank"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="tw" href="https://twitter.com/raygun_lx" target="_blank"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="header">
                        <img src="images/header.png" alt="header"/>
                    </div>
                <row>
                    <div class="btnsCont">
                        <button class="mrgr" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal">Doação</button>
                        <input type="button" value="Dúvidas" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:me@anydomainname.com'" />
                    </div>
                </row>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="show2" class="patrocinios faded">
            <ul>
                <li> 
                    <a href="https://www.ray-gun.pt/?page_id=2015&lang=pt">
                        <img src="images/raygun_logo.png" alt="Ray Gun" />
                     </a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.cvidaepaz.pt/site/">
                        <img src="images/comvidapaz_logo.png" alt="Com Vida e Paz" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://cercizimbra.org.pt">
                        <img src="images/cercizimbra_logo.png" alt="CERCI" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.ajudadeberco.pt/">
                        <img src="images/ajudaberco_logo.png" alt="Ajuda de Berço" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Heres the pertinent CSS

```
#skipbtn{
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
#vloop{
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.patrocinios{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

And the jquery that's working right now.

```
function fade() {
            $('#v1, #skipbtn').delay(50000).fadeOut(100).hide(0);
            $('#vloop').delay(50000).fadeIn(100);
        }
        fade();
        $(".faded").each(function(i) {
          $(this).delay(50000).fadeIn();
        });
```

This example: [Adding a Skip Button to FastForward a .fadeIn / .fadeOut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062908/adding-a-skip-button-to-fastforward-a-fadein-fadeout) was the one closest to mine and it's exactly the same  goal, but I when I try multiple selectors in the first function's fadeIn line it doesn't work. 
I really don't know how to overcome this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: With the help of a friend I figured it out. Had to change the functions to this

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a friend, I've accomplished my goal. I had to change the entire function.
I'll post it here if anyone else runs into the same problem.

```
var vid1 = $('#v1').find('video');
        var vid2 = $('#vloop').find('video');

        $(vid1).on("ended", function() {
            playVideo2();
        });

        $(vid2).on("ended", function() {
            playVideo1();
        });


        function playVideo2() {
            $('#v1, #skipbtn').fadeOut(50).hide(0);
            $('#vloop').fadeIn(50);
            videoPlaying = "video2";
            $(".faded").each(function(i) {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });

            $(vid2)[0].play();
            $(vid1)[0].pause();
        }

        function playVideo1() {
            $('#vloop').fadeOut(50).hide(0);
            $('#v1').fadeIn(50);
             $(".faded").each(function(i) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });

            videoPlaying = "video1";
            $(vid1)[0].play();
            $(vid2)[0].pause();
        }
        playVideo1();


        $('#skipbtn').on('click', function() {
            if (videoPlaying == "video1") {
                playVideo2();
            } else if (videoPlaying == "video2") {
                playVideo1();
            }

        });
```

Comment: FYI, `hide(0)` is unnecessary - could / should be simply `.hide()`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.